# How to put web service client in wait mode until execute my web service in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, salesforce

I've developed a web service in ASP.NET, To process the request it is taking 1 to 10 minutes.But my web service client can wait maximum 2 minutes so how can I handle this situation in ASP.NET web service i.e., how to send a request to web service client to wait for some time.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: what do you mean "can wait only 2 minutes"? Where that restriction comes from? I mean you can setup your timeouts in config files usually

Comment: my client(salesforce) can wait only 2 minutes

Answer (score 0):

In salesforce you're on a cloud platform which you share server resources with others. Their limits enforced so that you'll make efficient and well performing design choices that do not heavily (ab)use resources.

If your service takes 10 minutes, I would opt for  an asynchronous setup where your ASP.net service replies to salesforce by invoking the SOAP or REST API or a custom APEX web/restservice.